# How to remove extra duplicated elements in each row of a matrix in matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, jagged-arrays

Let's say I have a matrix

```
A = [2 3 2 5 6 7 2; 
     1 2 5 4 5 6 7; 
     7 5 3 9 8 1 2];
```

How do I remove `2`s and keep one `2` in the first row and keep only one `5` in the second row?

Comment: The result can't be a matrix anymore, because each row will have a different length. Which type of result do you want? Cell array of row vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find out which values are duplicates within the row, you can do something like this:

```
[vals, col_idx]  = sort(A,2);
idx = bsxfun(@plus,(col_idx-1)*size(A,1), (1:size(A,1))');
is_duplicate(idx(:,2:end)) = vals(:,1:end-1) == vals(:,2:end);
is_duplicate = reshape(is_duplicate, size(A));
```

is_duplicate =

```
 0     0     1     0     0     0     1
 0     0     0     0     1     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

From there, it depends what outcome you are looking for.  You could set the duplicates to `NaN` or some other value, or you could set them to `NaN`, but then shift them to the end of the row, using something like the following:

```
col_idx = cumsum(~is_duplicate, 2);
idx = bsxfun(@plus,(col_idx-1)*size(A,1), (1:size(A,1))');
A_new = nan(size(A));
A_new(idx(~is_duplicate)) = A(~is_duplicate);
```

A_new =

```
 2     3     5     6     7   NaN   NaN
 1     2     5     4     6     7   NaN
 7     5     3     9     8     1     2
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what i wanted,

Answer (score 4):

The result can't be a matrix anymore, because each row will have a different length. You can obtain the result as a *cell array of row vectors* as follows:

```
B = mat2cell(A, ones(size(A,1),1)); %// convert matrix to cell array of its rows
B = cellfun(@(x) unique(x,'stable'), B, 'uniformoutput', 0); %// stably remove duplicates
```

For your example matrix

```
A = [2 3 2 5 6 7 2; 
     1 2 5 4 5 6 7; 
     7 5 3 9 8 1 2];
```

this gives

```
B{1} =
     2     3     5     6     7
B{2} =
     1     2     5     4     6     7
B{3} =
     7     5     3     9     8     1     2
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. It is a nice code but i prefer to keep it as matrix rather than  row vectors. I will take dan-man answer. Have a nice day

Comment: @Gaze Of course! I wasn't sure what you wanted. Have a nice day too!